# How to get this Json Form?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to write a php script like this but I don't know how I can do it

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TIME",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        }
]}
```

And this is my php script

```
<?php

require ('config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
$query = "select * from playernews";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = array();
echo mysqli_error($conn);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

This is my php code script so if anyone can help me?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Help you in what? You want obtain the above json from db? Have you checked if the db query returns valid result?

Comment: You following this tutorial? http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

require ('config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "select * from playernews";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = array();
echo mysqli_error($conn);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}

$data = array(
    'feed' => $rows
);

echo json_encode($data); // now will get you same format as you wanted
?>
```

Comment: Sir this give me this form

{"feed":{"id":"1","name":"National Geographic Channel","image":"http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/cosmos.jpg","status":"\\\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\\\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \\\"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\\\"","profilePic":"http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/nat.jpg","timeStamp":"2016-02-26 03:14:00","url":"http:\/\/ti.me\/1qW8MLB","PlayerNo":"1"}}

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be. Tested and works for me in most php versions as seen on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21af0f6c0ae414fdaf072ba356b7ed1150b9d788

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't do that. **JSON is meant to transfer data** from one system to another, not as a debug medium or output format. The additional whitespace won't facilitate the JSON's main goal.

That being said, have a look at [the docs for `json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

There is an option **`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`** which you can pass into the function and that should help you achieve what you want:

```
json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm little dumb, but I don't understand where are “additional whitespace”

Comment: Well, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT indents the JSON string with four spaces in order to make it look nice. Those spaces are unnecessary purely from the perspective of the system consuming the JSON. This makes the string longer than it has to be.

Comment: I know the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT constant, and I know that they extends string. I don't understand when you say “additional whitespace won't facilitate the JSON's main goal” and then “(use) JSON_PRETTY_PRINT”. In simple terms, I don't fully understand the logic of your argumentation. Please note that my english is bad, if my explanation sounds disapproval it's not my intention. BTW, I was only interested in understand your argumentation, I'm sorry if I made you waste time. <3

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you shouldn't use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, but if you really really want the string to be formatted, I won't keep you from it.